# TikZ: Can one combine two draw commands (one with options, the other without) into on statement?

Tags: tikz-pgf

My code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw
      [->] (0, 0) |- (1, 0);
    \draw
           (1, 0) |- (2, 1);

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It is possible to use a single `draw` command to achieve the same result (arrow tip appears only at point (1, 0))?

Thank you for your effort in advance!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, draw the lines without arrow and the line with arrow comes last:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[->]
      (1, 0) |- (2, 1)
      (0, 0) -- (1, 0);

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Hello @Heiko Oberdiek! Thank you for your answer! I like it most. One thing: The `|-` operation between `(0, 0)` and `(1, 0)` isn't needed, right? `--` is enough?

Comment: @Su-47 Yes, `(0, 0) -- (1, 0)` works. Answer updated.

Answer (score 5):

it is possible, but code is not (much) shorter than with two `\draw` commands:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
%%% first case
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw (0,0) edge[->] (1,0) (1,0) |- (2,1); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
%%% second case
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw   (1,0) edge[<-] (0,0) |- (2,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

in the both cases the result is the same:

[image]

Comment: Hello @Zarko! Thank you for your answer! That's an easy one! I don't have the experience with the `edge` command. I will read about it in the manual.